# Problem with voice responses in dialogflow cx - Genesys cloud

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I have integrated google Dialogflow CX in genesys cloud.

I'm developing Dialogflow CX integration and noticed that from calling Call Dialogflow CX Bot action till prompt in bot is heard it takes about 5 seconds, which is kind of long. I've got both my Genesys and CX project in USA locations.

Could you pls let me know how to fix it.